# Why isn't an .ejs file using the text passed trough res.render?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

This is just part of the whole code. Everything inside the code works except the line: 'res.render("shopping-lists", { tableCountEjs: 10 });'

The weird thing is that the console.log inside the .ejs file does return value 10, which is correct. But it doesn't display anything using the property tableCountEjs. I did try to change the tableCountEjs inside the for loop in the .ejs file for a number directly and it worked. Everything inside the app.post runs except the res.render.

I also used res.render with a property previously inside this code and it worked. Although it wasn't inside an sql query as its here.

So any help appreciated.

Javascript:

```
app.get("/shopping-lists", (req, res) => {
  res.render("shopping-lists", { tableCountEjs: null });
});

app.post("/lists", authUser.authenticateToken, (req, res) => {
    let emptyColumn;
    let completedQueries = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i < columnCount; i++) {
      connection.query(
        `SELECT COUNT(*) AS empty_count FROM producttables WHERE table${i} IS NOT NULL`,
        (err, results) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Empty error:", err);
          }

          emptyColumn = results[0].empty_count;
          if (emptyColumn > 0) {
            tableCount++;
          }

          completedQueries++;
          console.log(`Ocuppied column found: table${i}`);

          if (completedQueries === columnCount - 1) {
            console.log(tableCount);
            res.render("shopping-lists", { tableCountEjs: 10 });
          }
        }
      );
    }
  });
});
```

EJS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Shooping Lists</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/shopping-lists.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="title">
      <h1>Your shopping lists</h1>
    </div>
    <p><%= tableCountEjs %></p>   
      <% console.log(tableCountEjs) %>
      <% for (let i = 1; i < tableCountEjs + 1; i++) { %>
        <div class="element">
          <p>Table<%= i %></p>
        </div>
      <% } %>        
  </body>
</html>
```